# How to fix app crash caused due to attempt of reading field from a null reference?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, retrofit2

I am creating a sample app that sends notification to the driver when a rider requests pickup (like the uber app) I have a button for that functionality in the app.The app works fine and gets the driver but when i click on the button to call the driver the app crashes showing a nullpointerexception at   `if (response.body().success == 1) Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Request Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

this is the code

```
private void sendRequestToDriver(String driverId) {

    DatabaseReference tokens = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.token_tbl);

    tokens.orderByKey().equalTo(driverId)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        Token token = postSnapshot.getValue(Token.class);

                        String json_lat_lng = new Gson().toJson(new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

                        Notification data = new Notification("SKYLAKE",json_lat_lng);
                        Sender content = null;
                        if (token != null) {
                            content = new Sender(token.getToken(),data);
                        }

                        mService.sendMessage(content)
                                .enqueue(new Callback<FCMResponse>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<FCMResponse> call, Response<FCMResponse> response) {

                                        if (response.body().success == 1)
                                            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Request Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        else {
                                            Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Request Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(Call<FCMResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                                        Log.e("ERROR",t.getMessage());

                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}
```

**ERROR LOG**

```
03-23 16:46:35.606 18150-18150/com.joy.skylake.enlyftrider E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.joy.skylake.enlyftrider.Model.FCMResponse.success' on a null object reference
at com.joy.skylake.enlyftrider.Home$3$1.onResponse(Home.java:192)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:762)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
```

Comment: Post error log too

Comment: (response.body()) is null

Comment: okay. i have updated

Comment: check whether `response` and `response.body()` are null before trying to access their member.

Comment: Are you debug what is the value of `response.body().success`.

Comment: public interface IFCMService {
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type:application/json",
            "Authorization:key=MyAuthorizationKey"
    })
    @POST("fcm/send")
    Call<FCMResponse> sendMessage(@Body Sender body);
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You can check the value of `response.body().success` by showing a toast and It should be an integer. If it is a string then firstly you parse this string to integer.

Comment: I tried that.@EktaBhawsar

Comment: So, did you get what value is having `response.body().success`

Comment: have you solved your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (response.body() != null && response.body().success == 1) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your answers to give context to the code

Answer (score 0):

You can try yoda condition [Yoda Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

```
if (null != response.body() && 1 == response.body().success) {
   ...
}
```

[Error Code 400](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream) means an Invalid JSON in your request.

Please check this [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41560316/5514789)

Comment: it seems the body is still null. I have another app that should receive a notification once the request is sent but the notification isnt comming

Comment: yup body is null and code = 400. please check my updated answer. it has a link.

Comment: what should i change to fix it?

Comment: See your message is blank.

Comment: no its not. as i said i hve two apps (like uber driver and uber rider) when one clicks on Request Driver it sends a request to the driver app and this activity would start. the code is here  http://txt.do/dg70p

Comment: I'll be greatful to you if you kindly help me in sorting out this.